# Oracle table creation missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle

This should be a pretty simple problem but I just can't see what is wrong. I am trying to create a table with a few check and not null constraints on said table, however I am getting a missing right parenthesis error when trying to execute the command.

```
CREATE TABLE students (
     studentID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
    forename VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL, 
    surname VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR2(20),
    city VARCHAR2(15),
    postcode VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    dateOfBirth DATE() NOT NULL CHECK(dateOfBirth BETWEEN DATE '1999-01-01' AND SYSDATE), 
    gender VARCHAR2(10) CHECK(gender = 'male' OR gender = 'female' OR gender = 'both'),
    category VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL CHECK(category = 'first year undergraduate' OR caregory = 'postgraduate'),
    fulltimeStudent VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CHECK(fulltimeStudent = 'yes' OR fulltimeStudent = 'no'),
    nationality VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    smoker VARCHAR(5) CHECK(smoker = 'yes' OR smoker = 'no') AND NOT NULL,
    specialNeeds VARCHAR(30),
    additionalComments VARCHAR(50),
    status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL CHECK(status = 'placed' or status = 'waiting')
    );
```

Full error below - 
[image]

Comment: `dateOfBirth DATE()` change it to `DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for parenthesis at "DATE()".
Also, you cannot use SYSDATE in check constraints, you may wish to use a trigger instead, and there's a typo at "CAREGORY".

You can run it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
     studentID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
    forename VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL, 
    surname VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR2(20),
    city VARCHAR2(15),
    postcode VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL, 
    gender VARCHAR2(10) CHECK(gender = 'male' OR gender = 'female' OR gender = 'both'),
    category VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL CHECK(category = 'first year undergraduate' OR category = 'postgraduate'),
    fulltimeStudent VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CHECK(fulltimeStudent = 'yes' OR fulltimeStudent = 'no'),
    nationality VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    smoker VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CHECK(smoker = 'yes' OR smoker = 'no'),
    specialNeeds VARCHAR(30),
    additionalComments VARCHAR(50),
    status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL CHECK(status = 'placed' or status = 'waiting')
    );
```

Edit-Added docs reference on sysdate in check constraints:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm

> Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following
>   constructs:
>
> ```
> Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions
>
> Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE, LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE, SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and USERENV)
>
> Calls to user-defined functions
>
> Dereferencing of REF columns (for example, using the DEREF function)
>
> Nested table columns or attributes
>
> The pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, or ROWNUM
>
> Date constants that are not fully specified
> ```

Comment: I always assumed you could use SYSDATE in a check constraint, but learn something new every day! Thank you.

Comment: @DaveDavidson - it kind of makes sense, if you decide from the outset that a constraint is something that should be either true or false, the answer shouldn't be "it depends." What if the constraint is true today, you are allowed to change the record (add, update, delete) and tomorrow the constraint is no longer satisfied? That would be a great way to have a big mess in your database.